# Adding few more conditions to find nearby places in mysql - google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to get nearby place using a solution I found on google's documents [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

The problem is I want to add few more filters in search

Original solution

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * cos( radians( mapLan ) ) * cos( radians( mapLon ) - radians(" . $row1['tubeLon'] . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * sin( radians( mapLan ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM " . $table . " HAVING distance < 2500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

What I want it to add this filter in the above statement

```
SIZE between $firstrange and $secondrange"
```

I tried this but didn't provide the required result

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * cos( radians( mapLan ) ) * cos( radians( mapLon ) - radians(" . $row1['tubeLon'] . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * sin( radians( mapLan ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM " . $table . " HAVING distance < 2500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 and SIZE between $firstrange and $secondrange";
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can't I add these conditions by just putting `AND` between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can add conditions using AND, but you have to add them to your WHERE or HAVING clause, not at the end of the statement:

```
SELECT *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * cos( radians( mapLan  ) ) * cos( radians( mapLon ) - radians(" . $row1['tubeLon'] . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $row1['tubeLan'] . ") ) * sin( radians( mapLan ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM " . $table . " 
WHERE SIZE between $firstrange and $secondrange
HAVING distance < 2500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20 ;
```

(i suppose SIZE is a column in your table)